# Empty entry in ElementList SimpleXML

Tags: android, simple-framework

my question is simple, but I can't find nothing about it.

I Have a list class and an entry class for XML Serialization:

```
@Root(name = "entries")
public class List {

    @ElementList(required = false, entry = "entry", inline = true, empty = true)
    private List<Entry> entries;
}

@Root
public class Entry {

    @Element(name = "entry_id", required = true)
    private long id;

    @Element(name = "text", required = true)
    private String Text;
}
```

I'm trying to parse this XML, which don't have any entries in the list:

```
<entries>
   <entry />
<entries>
```

The follow error is returned:

```
W/System.err(3335): org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=entry_id, required=true, type=void) on field 'id' private long com.android.apps.model.Entry.id for class com.android.apps.model.Entry at line 2
```

What am I doing wrong? The ElementList is set empty = true and required = false.
anybody can help?

Comment: It does have one in the list, it's an empty one though and so fails the check for having an id attribute. So your real issue is why is that empty tag in the output?

Comment: I see. The XML is generated by another system. In that case, I wanna know if simple framework has some way to identify the empty item in the list and ignore it. Is there a way?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, can't think of a reason to have it either. Only thing I can think of. Is 1) Report this as a bug 2) Fix the Xml before you deserialize it.

Comment: Yes, I also think so. Well, thanks a lot, now I'm sure that my code is right at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for empty elements manually:

```
@Root(name = "entries")
@Convert(List.ListConverter.class) // Set the converter
public class List
{
    @ElementList(required = false, entry = "entry", inline = true, empty = true)
    private java.util.List<Entry> entries;


    public void add(Entry e)
    {
        // Just for testing
        entries.add(e);
    }



    static class ListConverter implements Converter<List>
    {
        @Override
        public List read(InputNode node) throws Exception
        {
            List l = new List();
            InputNode child = node.getNext("entry");

            while( child != null)
            {
                if( child.isEmpty() == true ) // child is an empty tag
                {
                    // Do something if entry is empty
                }
                else // child is not empty
                {
                    Entry e = new Persister().read(Entry.class, child); // Let the Serializer read the Object
                    l.add(e);
                }

                child = node.getNext("entry");
            }

            return l;
        }


        @Override
        public void write(OutputNode node, List value) throws Exception
        {
            // Not required for reading ...
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
Serializer ser = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy()); // Set AnnotationStrategy here!
List l = ser.read(List.class, yourSourceHere);
```

**Documentation:**

- [Converter](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Converter.html)
- [AnnotationStrategy](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/AnnotationStrategy.html)

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the list is completely filled with empty tags. Can you improve your answer?

Answer (score 0):

**To avoid the error in parse do one should place annotation tags @set e @get**

```
@Root(name = "entries", strict = false)
public class List {

@set:ElementList(required = false, entry = "entry", inline = true, empty = true)
@get:ElementList(required = false, entry = "entry", inline = true, empty = true)
    private List<Entry> entries;

}

@Root
public class Entry {

    @set:Element(name = "entry_id", required = true)
    @get:Element(name = "entry_id", required = true)
    private long id;

    @set:Element(name = "text", required = true)
    @get:Element(name = "text", required = true)
    private String Text;
}
```

Comment: You should write your answer in English on stackoverflow