# Simple XML - Handle empty string to type conversion

Tags: java, simple-framework

I am trying to use the Simple framework to deserialize some data provided by a third-party provider into Java objects. The incoming data is POST-ed to an HTTP server, and from there my code needs to take over.

The XML looks like this:

```
<SomeElement attrib1="foo" attrib2="1337" attrib3="" />
```

There are many more attributes - nearly 50 of them.

My Java class is:

```
public class SomeElement {
    @Attribute private String attrib1;
    @Attribute private int attrib2;
    @Attribute(required=false, empty="0") private int attrib3;
}
```

This does not parse, though. I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.transform.IntegerTransform.read(IntegerTransform.java:55)
```

It is not clear to my how I can get Simple XML to parse "" correctly to something usable. I am probably missing some magic incantation of the annotations, but I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If all fails, implement a [**`Converter`**](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Converter.html) for the element.

Here are two examples how to do this (related to null / empty elements):

- [Simpleframework. Can nulls be retained in collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386175/simpleframework-can-nulls-be-retained-in-collections/26434545#26434545)
- [Empty entry in ElementList SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581789/empty-entry-in-elementlist-simplexml/21706721#21706721)